# Passing variables to Evens in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How i can pass some variables to an Event in Laravel 5.5?
I have tried in several mode but not working. Here is my code. Someone have any suggestion?
Basically i need to update the number of followers via socket. Server using Redis and Socket.io and work as well

```
 Route::post('follow', function() {
    $negozio = Input::get('id_azienda');
    $followers = new \App\Models\Followers;
    $followers->entry_by = \Session::get('uid');
    $followers->id_azienda = $negozio;
    $followers->save();
    $this->variabili['negozio'] = $negozio;
    $this->variabili['followers'] = $followers->count();
    event(new \App\Events\Follow(), $this->variabili);


});
```

And this is the Event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class Follow implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $variabili;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'count'=> $variabili['followers'],
            'negozio'=> $variabili['negozio']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as Constructor's parameter in your Follow Event class, and if you need it as public field do like this:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class Follow implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($variabili)
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'count'=> $variabili['followers'],
            'negozio'=> $variabili['negozio']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

And pass him parameters in this way:

```
Route::post('follow', function() {
    $negozio = Input::get('id_azienda');
    $followers = new \App\Models\Followers;
    $followers->entry_by = \Session::get('uid');
    $followers->id_azienda = $negozio;
    $followers->save();
    $this->variabili['negozio'] = $negozio;
    $this->variabili['followers'] = $followers->count();
    event(new \App\Events\Follow($this->variabili));


});
```